# Multi line binary file read line by line and convert to char in python

Tags: python-3.x

My text file have data as :

01100110011010010111001001110011011101000010000001101100011010010110111001100101
0111001101100101011000110110111101101110011001000010000001101100011010010110111001100101
01110100011010000110100101110010011001000010000001101100011010010110111001100101

so, I need to convert this data file to English by python.
but my programme get some error as :

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: ''

Please help me to solve this

```
def bit2strings():
    with open('test_doc.txt', 'r' ) as f:
        x = (f.read())
        for line in x.split(' '):
            data = line
            if data =='':
                print(data)
                break
            else:
                data = f.read(8)
                plaintext = chr(int(data, 2))
                print(plaintext, end='')
                data = f.read(8)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is not more advance coding part. but how ever lastly write proper programme to solve my problem. I am a beginner to python. so then please give me some comment to do advance this coding part more than this. this is my coding part :

```
def bit2strings():
    with open('test_doc.txt', 'r') as f:
        for i in f:
            #print(i)
            for j in range(len(i)//8):
                s = ((i[j * 8:j * 8 + 8]))
                #print(s)            
                get_string = ''.join(chr(int(s, 2)))
                print(get_string, end='')
            print(end='\n')
        

if __name__=='__main__':
    bit2strings()
```